# XSL Process attributes in an order

Tags: xslt

I need to process attributes (of any node that has them) in a particular order. For example:

```
<test>
    <event 
        era  ="modern"
        year ="1996"
        quarter = "first"
        day = "13"
        month= "January"
        bcad ="ad"
        hour ="18"
        minute = "23"
        >The big game began.</event>
    <happening 
        era  ="modern"
        day = "18"
        bcad ="ad"
        month= "February"
        hour ="19"
        minute = "24"
        >The big game ended.</happening>
    <other>Before time existed.</other>
</test>
```

This

```
<xsl:template match="test//*">
    <div>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <span class="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </span>
</xsl:template>
```

would format things as I need them. That is, I'd get

```
<div><span class="era">modern</span>
     <span class="year">1996</span>
     <span class="quarter">first</span>
     <span class="day">13</span>
     <span class="month">January</span>
     <span class="bcad">ad</span>
     <span class="hour">18</span>
     <span class="minute">23</span>The big game began.</div>
<div><span class="era">modern</span>
     <span class="day">18</span>
     <span class="bcad">ad</span>
     <span class="month">February</span>
     <span class="hour">19</span>
     <span class="minute">24</span>The big game ended.</div>
<div>Before time existed.</div>
```

(though without the newlines I've added here for legibility).

But the order of the attributes wouldn't (necessarily) be right.

To fix that, I could change `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />` to `<xsl:call-template name="atts" />` and add a template that applies templates in the needed order, like this:

```
<xsl:template match="test//*">
    <div>
        <xsl:call-template name="atts" />
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="atts">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@era" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@bcad" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@year" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@quarter" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@month" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@day" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@hour" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@minute" />        
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <span class="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </span>
</xsl:template>
```

Is this the best-practices way to process attributes in a specified order? I keep wondering if there is a way that uses keys or a global variable.

I need to use XSLT 1.0 and in the real case, there are several dozen attributes, not just eight.

Answer (score 1):

In contrast to elements for example, the order of attributes is not significant in XML, i.e. XPath and XSLT may process them in any order. Thus, the only way to force a given order, is to specify it somehow. One way is to call them explicitly as in your last code example. You can also extract all attribute names and store them in a separate XML file, e.g. something like

```
<attributes>
  <attribute>era</attribute>
  <attribute>year</attribute>
  <attribute>month</attribute>
  ...
<attributes>
```

Now you can load these elements with the document() function and iterate over all *attribute* elements:

```
<xsl:variable name="attributes" select="document('attributes.xml')//attribute"/>
...
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:variable name="self" select="."/>
  <xsl:for-each select="$attributes">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$self/@*[name()=current()]"/>
  </xsl:for-each>    
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Except that there is no need to put the list of attributes in a separate XML file--it can and very likely should go right into the XSLT file itself (and then be referenced using the document() function with no arguments.

Comment: Yes, that's right. However, I wouldn't extract the attributes manually but write a stylesheet that extracts them from a given XML file. To me, it's much easier to maintain such a list in a separate file rather than copying everything into the stylesheet each time the attributes are extracted and reordered again. But that's probably just a personal preference.

Comment: @Martin Do you see how I could add a delimiter between each attribute? Let's say the apply-template just returned the value, and the attributes were month, day and year. I'd like "5/16/2012". With your approach, I can't test for pos()!=last() since those functions count all attributes in the for-each, not just those where name()=current().

Comment: @JPM: You could check if further attributes of the same element are going to be processed after the current one, e.g. by adding this test after the xsl:apply-templates statement: `<xsl:if test="$self/@*[name()=current()/following::attribute]">/<xsl:if>`